# How to delete XML string using java

Tags: java, android, xml

How to delete a string of the XML node using java. I have two nodes in same name with different values. I want to delete first node of XML file. example `<node1>value1</node1><node1>value2<node1>` in this example i want to delete node 1 of value 1. Please guide me how to do this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is show in this example, how it could be done
 
http://www.roseindia.net/xml/dom/RemoveElement.shtml

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have parsed the xml document into a DOM structure. Then you can call the `removeChild` method of the parent node to remove an element from a DOM tree.